# Attempting to count a certain string and how many times it repeats. Also, replacing characters with other characters. All from a file read

Tags: string, character, python-2.x

I've got code so far that seems to change letters. However, this is how it should be changed:
All G become C. All C become G. All T become A. And all A become T.

This is where my problem is happening. As seen, for example, since T becomes A and A becomes T, the code is just leaving it as a T. Because it's changing it to A and then just changing that same character back to T. I need to make it so it makes all the changes at the same time so it doesn't overlap like that. Same thing with G to C and C to G.

This is a sample of what's inside the text file:
GTCGACTGCACTCGCCCCCACGAGAGAACAGTATTTAAGGAGCTGCGAAGGTCCAAGTCATGCATTATTG
TCTCAGTGCAGTTGTCAGTTGCAGTTCAGCAGACGGGCTAACGAGTACTTGCATCTCTTCAAATTTACTT
AATTGATCAAGTAAGTAGCAAAAGGGCACACAATTGAAGGAAATTCTTGTTTAATTGAATTTATTATGCA

Basically just massive string like that. I need to reverse all letters as outlined above. Likewise, I am trying to count the number of times the following string occurs: "GCAA" before changing the characters.

This is my code so far:

```
f = open("filename.txt", "r")
from string import maketrans
table = maketrans("G", "C")
table = maketrans("C", "G")
table = maketrans("T", "A")
table = maketrans("A", "t")
print(f.read().translate(maketrans('G','C')))
print(f.read().translate(maketrans('C','G')))
print(f.read().translate(maketrans('T','A')))
print(f.read().translate(maketrans('A','T')))

print(table)
```

I don't know how I would go about counting anything though, so I haven't gotten to that part yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single call to maketrans like this:

```
from string import maketrans
table = maketrans("GCTA", "CGAT")
f = open("filename.txt", "r")
input = f.read()
print(input.translate(table))
print(input.count('GCAA'))
```

Comment: Oh, great. It works! So basically doing a single line maketrans like this bypasses the issue I was having. Now it does change A to T and T to A without any overlaps, etc.

What about counting an occurrence of a particular string/sequence of characters such as "GCAA"? I tried looking up some doc and see that str.count(" ") might be of some use, but I can't get it to work. For instance, counting GCAA BEFORE switching the letters. And also, counting GCAA AFTER the letters are switched with the maketrans.

Comment: 1) Yes it does. 2) see the last line :-)

Comment: So, this seems to be counting GCAA after the switch of the letters is made. What if I wanted to count also before the switching? I can just create another variable before the maketrans line and then output that at the end?

Comment: g = open("filename.txt", "r")
input2 = g.read()
print(input2.count('GCAA'))

Does adding these lines to the very beginning do it correctly? I'm not sure because I am getting the same number both times. I just took the translate out and made the read 'g' instead 'f' to have different variables

Comment: Actually, it counts the GCAA occurrences before the translation, since the input variable is not modified by the translate function.

Comment: If you want to count the occurrences after the translation, do something like this: 
    result = input.translate(table)
    print(result.count('GCAA'))

Comment: You are free to rename the variables how ever you like, as long as you do it consistently.

Comment: Great. That worked! Also, last question, sorry to keep changing/adding extra criteria in. But, how would I go about reversing the entire file? As in, just change it from end to start.
Example: I am here. Instead, it would be read as "Here am I."

Comment: Try something like appending [::-1] after the string variable, for example: print( result[::-1] )

Comment: But what string variable do I even have? I have to define the f.read() to a string variable and then do the ::-1 ?

Comment: In my example above, 'input' is the name of the string variable (see line number 4), in which you read the content of your file.

Comment: Ok, great. I figured it out. However, I was wondering, this is reversing the actual string/characters. For instance, CGAT is becoming TAGC. Instead of reversing each letter like this, is there was a to just change the way it is read. As in, if the sentence is: "This is an example." I want to reverse it in a way that would make it "Example an is This." Keeping the words the same but just reading the sentence backwards. I am reading doc on a reversed() method but am not able to do it

Comment: print ' '.join(reversed("question original the to relation no has This".split()))

Comment: Ha, sorry. Back on track: What about trying to count the "GCAA" AFTER a reverse? Right now, I have it counting BEFORE anything is done. Then it's counting AFTER letters are replaced. But now what if I want to count after letters replaced+reversed? OR what if I want to REVERSE first, THEN change letters and count?

Comment: Sorry, but you keep changing your requests and I refuse to answer anymore; stackoverflow is a Question and Answers site; it is not IRC. Besides you can simply try to see what will happen, by assigning the results of each call to differently named variables and swapping code lines, thus answering your own questions in no time.